# Python Robot, my code isn't reconizing the variables

Tags: python, robotics

Write a Python 3 program to model driving a robot around in an environment. The robot has the following attributes:

```
x-coordinate

y-coordinate

fuel amount
```

It can do the following things:

```
move left, right, up, and down

display its current status

fire its laser
```

The robot should begin at location (10, 10), and should start with a fuel amount of 100.

When told to move, the robot's fuel should decrease by 5, and it should move one unit in the desired direction (Left should subtract one from the x-coordinate and right should add 1 to the it. Down should add 1 to the y-coordinate, and up should subtract one from it). Displaying the status should print the location and fuel to the console in the format: "(x-coordinate, y-coordinate) - Fuel: fuel-amount", such as (9, 4) - Fuel: 75.

Firing the laser should output "Pew! Pew!" to the console and reduce the fuel-amount by 15.

If the robot does not have enough fuel for any of the above actions, it should display the text, "Insufficient fuel to perform action". In that case it should not move, fire the laser, or reduce the fuel.
User Interface

The user is presented with a prompt: "Enter command: " and can enter any of the following commands:

```
left

right

up

down

fire

status

quit
```

Any other commands should be ignored, and the user re-prompted. When the user enters the quit command, the program should display the text, "Goodbye" and then exit.

```
class robot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=10
        self.y=10
        self.fuel=100

        def right(self):
            if self.fuel>=5:
                self.x+=1
                self.fuel-=5
            else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

        def left(self):
            if self.fuel>=5:
                self.x-=1
                self.fuel-=5
            else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

        def up(self):
            if self.fuel>=5:
                self.y-=1
                self.fuel-=5
            else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

        def down(self):
            if self.fuel>=5:
                self.y+=1
                self.fuel-=5
            else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

        def fire(self):
            if self.fuel>=15:
                print("Pew! Pew!")
                self.fuel-=15
            else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

        def status(self):
            print("({}, {}) - Fuel: {}".format(self.x, self.y, self.fuel))

        def quit(self):
            print("Goodbye")

        def main():
            while robot().fuel >= 5:
                command = input("Enter command: ")

            if command == "right":
                robot().right()
            elif command == "left":
                robot().left()
            elif command == "up":
                robot().up()
            elif command == "down":
                robot().down()
            elif command == "fire":
                robot().fire()
            elif command == "status":
                robot().status()
            elif command == "quit":
                robot().quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: is the indentation of your code correct? could you specify the error you're encountering and in which context?

Answer (score 1):

- Your class should rather be named `Robot` with an capital in order to respect Python's naming conventions.
- The `main` function shouldn't be indented, as it now appears as a method of your class.
- in `main()`, you create a new instance of robot on each test, which you immediately discard. Create one at the start of the function and use it all along afterwards.

So, this should look like:

```
class Robot:             # naming convention, capitalized
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=10
        self.y=10
        self.fuel=100

    def right(self):
        if self.fuel>=5:
            self.x+=1
            self.fuel-=5
        else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

    def left(self):
        if self.fuel>=5:
            self.x-=1
            self.fuel-=5
        else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

    def up(self):
        if self.fuel>=5:
            self.y-=1
            self.fuel-=5
        else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

    def down(self):
        if self.fuel>=5:
            self.y+=1
            self.fuel-=5
        else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

    def fire(self):
        if self.fuel>=15:
            print("Pew! Pew!")
            self.fuel-=15
        else: print("Insufficient fuel to perform action")

    def status(self):
        print("({}, {}) - Fuel: {}".format(self.x, self.y, self.fuel))

    def quit(self):
        print("Goodbye")

def main():
    robot = Robot()     # create an instance
    while robot.fuel >= 5:
        command = input("Enter command: ")

    if command == "right":
        robot.right()
    elif command == "left":
        robot.left()
    elif command == "up":
        robot.up()
    elif command == "down":
        robot.down()
    elif command == "fire":
        robot.fire()
    elif command == "status":
        robot.status()
    elif command == "quit":
        robot.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining python, programming concepts and correcting the code. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Intend error is also there

```
def main():
    while robot().fuel >= 5:
        command = input("Enter command: ")

        if command == "right":
            robot().right()
        elif command == "left":
            robot().left()
        elif command == "up":
            robot().up()
        elif command == "down":
            robot().down()
        elif command == "fire":
            robot().fire()
        elif command == "status":
            robot().status()
        elif command == "quit":
            robot().quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

other than calling `main()` rather than `robot.main()`, the main issue is that `main` is a static method, and doesn't have access to the instance variables ('self') of any specific robot instance. What you should probably do is pass 'self' to main, and use 'self' on all the variables.